# How to make C# method generic so it could be used by different classes

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, refactoring

How could I make this method more like a generic - that can be used by different classes

Here is my method which should be used now by two `classes`, since now it was invoked only in one place and input param was `IdentDto`, and now I should use it on one more place where I should pass as param class `User`.

Here's method definition:

```
private IdentificationResponse Identification (IdentDto request)
{
    var customRequestion = new CustomRequest
    {
        FirstADDRESS = request.Company.Address.FirstAddress,
        SecondADDRESS = request.Company.Address.SecondAddress,
        CompanyTown = request.Company.Address.City,
    };

    if (request.Company.HasUserAdded)
    {
        customRequestion.Name = request.User.Name;
        customRequestion.Surname = request.User.Surname;
    }

    return null; // Not important for this case
}
```

`IdentDto` contains `UserDto` which contains `User` inside and it looks like this:

```
public class IdentDto
{
    public UserDto User { get; set; }
    public CompanyDto Company { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine when this method is used by `IdentDto`, but since User contains `Company` prop in himself, sometimes it would
be awesome to be able to receive `User` also as a parameter and `User's` class looks like this:

```
public class User 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string SurName { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

And If I change a parameter to `User` instead of `IdentDto` than I could access directly to `Name` and `Surname` so code might look like this:

```
private IdentificationResponse Identification (IdentDto request)
{
    var customRequestion = new CustomRequest
    {
        FirstADDRESS = request.Company.Address.Address1,
        SecondADDRESS = request.Company.Address.Address2,
        CompanyTown = request.Company.Address.City,
    };

    if (request.Company.HasUserAdded)
    {
        customRequestion.Name = request.Name; // Here I would get issue cuz it's not anymore request.User.Name;
        customRequestion.Surname = request.Surname; // Here I would get only issue cuz it's not anymore request.User.Surname; now it become request.Surname because I would use User class for example..
    }

    return null; // Not important for this case
}
```

So as you can see If I could pass user than I could access directly to that params, but that's no solution because I can not change
it likes that because some else, for example, needs to send `IdentDto` as param...

So I'm wondering how could I redefine this method so the method could work with different classes at the same time.

Thanks a lot!

Cheers!

Comment: The second example uses the same 'IdentDto ' as parameter did you mean User instead?

Comment: @CyberProgs yes you are right, my misstake

Comment: Have User and UserDto implement the IUser interface {Name, SurName}.  Then have Company and CompanyDTO implement the ICompany interface {Address1, Address2, City}.  Then have your method take an IUser and ICompany.  You can provide overrides if you want for your IdentDto and User classes that just recall into the non-override.

Comment: Or if this is a one-off, then just have 2 overrides (IdentDto and User) that feed your method the 6 things it needs.

Comment: You can accept type `object` and use switch pattern matching but I wouldnt recommend it. Interface would be best.

Answer (score 1):

You could make `IdentDto` and `User` to implement an interface, let's say:

```
public interface IMyInterface {

  public Company Company { get; }
  public string Name { get; }
  public string SurName { get; }
}

public class IdentDto : IMyInterface {
    public string Name { get => User.Name; }
    public string SurName { gt => User.SurName; }
}

public class User: IMyInterface { }
```

And then pass to your method a reference to the interface instead of a specific type. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way:

```
private IdentificationResponse Identification(Company company, string Name, string Surname)
{
 ... Your old logic here ...
}

private IdentificationResponse Identification(IdentDto req) => 
  Identification(req.Company, req.User.Name, req.User.Surname)

private IdentificationResponse Identification(User req) => 
  Identification(req.Company, req.Name, req.SurName)
```

The adapter (via extensions) way:

```
public static class UserExtensions
{
  public static IdentDto ToIdentDto(this User u)
  {
    return new IdentDto
    {
      User = new UserDto {Name = u.Name, SurName = u.SurName},
      Company = u.Company.ToCompanyDto()
    }
  }
}
public static class CompanyExtensions
{
  public static CompanyDto ToCompanyDto(this Company c)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then you can call your method via `var i = Identification(user.ToUserDto());`

The implicit type conversion way:

```
public class User 
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string SurName { get; set; }
  public Company Company { get; set; }
  public static implicit operator IdentDto(User u) =>new IdentDto
        {
          User = new UserDto {Name = u.Name, SurName = u.SurName},
          Company = new CompanyDto { ... }
        };
}
```

Or lastly, you can refactor into common interfaces (which is the most organized way to do it).